# Android enable next Item in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have `N records` in a *ListView*, by `default` I want to see `1st list item` as **enabled** and other `items` as **disabled**, to achieve same, I've written a small logic inside `isEnabled` method in an *Adapter* class and it `works`

```
@Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if(position == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Once user tap on *list item 1* (only then I want to enable **item number 2** in a list) and when user do tap on *list item 2* (which we just enabled, I want to enable **item number 3**)

And to achieve that I'm using following line of code:

```
int enableIndex = position + 1;
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(enableIndex), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
listview.getChildAt(enableIndex).setEnabled(true);
```

I can see very next item index when I tap on current item, but *unable* to make next item **enabled**

Comment: please also upvote my question as I have shown research efforts, I hope my question is useful and clear too... at least I can join group of experts to chat, once I get some points

Comment: Could you try call notifyDataSetChanged after tap to enable item ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a boolean field `enabled` in your model class, and update it. Then call `notifyItemChanged` for that particular position. Something like that..

Comment: I'm using ListView not RecyclerView, as I can't see notifyItemChanged anywhere in suggestion

Comment: I meant to call appropriate method which is similar to notifyItemChanged for listview..

Comment: Do you mean `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`?

Comment: Yes that one for ListView

Answer (score 0):

You just add holder.itemView.isEnable=enablePos==position line on your bindViewHolder fun.when you click on item view add below line.
enablePos=adapterPosition+1
notifyItemChanged(enablePos)

Comment: I added another field in model class as you suggested private boolean isEnabled; but not getting what to do now